# Trying to store every fifth record in the Iris dataset in R

Tags: r, dataset

Using the Iris data set in R, I'm trying to store every fifth record in a “test” dataset starting with the first record.

```
View(iris)
test<-iris[-idx,5]
```

This just showed me what's in the fifth column of the dataset. I'm looking to show every fifth row starting with the first. How exactly do I go about this? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `seq`

```
test <- iris[seq(1, nrow(iris), by = 5),]
```

---

Or using a logical vector to recycle to the end of the rows

```
test <- iris[c(TRUE, rep(FALSE, 4)),]
```

Comment: This is it. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method using modulus (`%%`):

```
test <- iris[seq.int(nrow(iris)) %% 5) == 1, ]
```